# Uncheck the checkbox after checked it

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have a column which is a checkbox.

```
 <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding GoodDeal, Converter={StaticResource ShortToBooleanConverter}}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_UnChecked"></CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I have the method `CheckBox_Check` in the code behind to handle the issue when the checkbox is checked.

Inside the method, I find some condition is not meet. So I pop out a message box. When the user click Yes, it will uncheck the checkbox automatically.

My thought is to add method in the code behind.

```
private void CheckBox_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    chkBox.IsChecked = false;
}
```

But how to raise this event in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using code behind event handlers and MVVM bindings are not a good mix, and can be the cause of you application not behaving as expected. 
I recommend you to keep all your logic in your view model if you are implementing a MVVM solution.

Here in this pseudo code I use the property you are binding to, but you may use commands as well.

```
  public short GoodDeal 
    {
       get {return _goodDeal; }
       set 
       {
          if (NotGoodDeal(value))
          {
              if ( UserConfirmDeal()  )
              {
                  _goodDeal = value;
              }
          }
          RaisePropertyChange();  
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your XAML: Unchecked="CheckBox_UnChecked"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a command on the messagebox button and bind it to your viewmodel, and set GoodDeal to false.